# MySql PHP tree view

Tags: php, mysql, treeview

I am building a web application for an affiliate program and on the `users` table I have this structure:

[image: Image showing structure]

Based on this MySql table I want every user to be able to see his tree, so I need this query:

1. The user to see who recruited him and who was recruited by him and I don't want the query to show other users that are recruited by the same recruited that recruited this user. 
   Basicly it should look this way:

[image: Image showing... something. The query maybe?]

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm really having a difficult time understanding what you're asking for... can you edit your question and provide more detail, perhaps ask in a different way?

Comment: I don't want the query to show other users that are recruited by the same recruited that recruited this user ?????

Comment: That's what I'm talking about @Joe :-)

Comment: @Joe check the last line on the second image, Thats what i am trying to describe.If I am one user and i want to see my genealogy. What i want is this user to be able to see only his recruiter and peoples that this one recruited not other users in the same level.

Comment: well looks to me like he needs a simple parent id recursion :) of course there are more efficient ways like nested sets but they have disadvantages as well...

Answer (score 0):

if your table structure really looks like this you ned to define a function or easier do it in a recursive lookup in your language (php), 
but its a really inefficient way.
read this article it deals with this recursive and other teqniques.

it explains storing of hirachical data in databases better than i could:
http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/hierarchical-data-database